# How the final keyword work with StringBuilder?

Tags: java

Why below code is not throwing any exception while final used?
`final StingBuilder sb=new StingBuilder("Satya");

sb.append("Pune");`

Comment: final does not mean immutable. It means the variable cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score 5):

`final` only says the variable cannot be reassigned. but the attributes of the variable can still be changed

`final` means in this case: that the reference to the object is final (it can only be assigned once), not the object itself.

The object itself can still be modified.

Answer (score 4):

`final` means shallow immutability.

Java only has primitive and reference variables and in this case `StringBuilder sb` is a *reference* to a `StringBuilder` and that reference is immutable.  ie. you can't do `sb = null;` later.

However, the object referenced is not made also immutable and you can still call methods which alter the StringBuilder via this reference.

Comment: I have never heard shallow immutability meaning that. My understanding is that shallow immutability means an object whose fields cannot be reassigned, whereas deep immutability means all the fields cannot be reassigned and are all either primitive or references to (deeply) immutable objects.

Comment: @PaulBoddington For me, it mean the same thing except in Java you can't have Objects for fields, only primitives or references so when you make them `final` they can't change but the object it points to can.

Answer (score 2):

`sb.append` doesn't assign a new value to `sb`, only mutates the state of the instance already referred by `sb`. Therefore it is allowed, even for `final` variables.

If, on the other hand, you added a second assignment to `sb`, such as `sb = null;`, it wouldn't pass compilation.